# Return aditional boolean value in sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have these tables:

```
A: id/id_B
   1/  13
   2/ 5

B: id/name/..
   1  name1 ..
   ...
   5  name5 ..
   13 name13 ..
```

And I need create a query to get these values:

```
id_B/name/is_in_A
1   name1  False
...
5   name5  True
13  name13 True
```

using SqlAlchemy
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Table B

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |
| 5 | name5 |

#### Table A

| id | id_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |

#### SQLAlchemy models code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, String

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db.db")
conn = engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "B"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_B = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("B.id"))
```

#### Select query code

```
base_query = select(B).add_columns(B.id.in_(select(A.id_B)))

for row in conn.execute(base_query).all():
    print(row)
```

#### Output

```
(1, 'name1', True)
(2, 'name2', False)
(3, 'name3', False)
(4, 'name4', True)
(5, 'name5', True)
```